# The magento2.3.6 home page will not show me anything

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Install magento 2.3.6, and it installed fine, but when opening the page it does not show anything, but the admin page there does work

[image]

Comment: any error in log file ???

Answer (score 0):

> Open This File :-

```
...\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

> A function isPathInDirectories added a line

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath);
```

> or refer below code function

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/After-Successful-Installation-Magento-Getting-Blank-Gray-page/m-p/114235#M5155